# How can I shorten the query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, request.querystring

I have an MVC Core application, and one of the forms on submit passes a too long query string:

> HTTP Error 404.15 - Not Found The request filtering module is
>   configured to deny a request where the query string is too long.

My action method looks like this:

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> ExportAsync(int? itemId, SelectActiveOrInactive activeOrInactiveItems = SelectActiveOrInactive.Active)
```

Here is the form:

```
<form asp-controller="Allocation" asp-action="Index">
```

And here is the submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Export" asp-controller="Allocation" asp-action="ExportAsync" formmethod="get" class="btn btn-primary form-control mr-1" />
```

The query string really contains too much stuff, but I only need `itemId` and `activeOrInactiveItems`, as you can see. Is there a way to shorten the query string and strip out everything I don't need? I would prefer not to touch web.config.

Comment: AFAIK the query string is built by the caller, so you should patch there.

Comment: If you can't get the caller to send less parameters, then either you'd need to strip the query string further up the stack from your application (e.g. in a load balancer, HAProxy etc.), or you'll have to update Web.config to increase the minimum query string length allowed or some IIS rewrite rules, otherwise the request will never get to your application code for you to change it.

Comment: @Martin Costello I added more code to my question. May I ask what you call caller?

Comment: When I made the action httppost instead of httpget, it worked. Could somebody explain this to me? Is it a real solution?

Comment: HTTP verbs like POST send data via the request *body*. While GET can *technically* have a body, according to spec, no real HTTP client (i.e. browser in this case) actually supports that. Instead, the data is included in the URI (i.e. via the query string) for GET requests.

Comment: @Chris Pratt Thank you for the explanation. So is that a good solution?

Comment: It depends. You should use the HTTP verb that is appropriate. If based on what you're doing POST is more appropriate anyways, then yes, as you should have been using POST in the first place. However, if this *should* be a GET, then it should remain a GET, and you should solve it in another way. Regardless, it makes no sense to send vast amounts of data that you don't want or need anyways, so more likely than not, you should simply look at just trimming your request so that only what you want is sent.

Comment: @Chris Pratt  But that was my original question, how to trim the request... Can't find a simple solution...

Comment: No, I mean stop sending the data in the first place. If this is a form on a web page, for example, remove the fields that you don't care about. Or, if you can't, then use a different form for this particular request. If you don't need the data, don't include it. Easy as that.

Comment: @Chris Pratt Thank you! If you make this your answer, I will mark it as such.

Comment: @DavidShochet By caller, I mean the client that initiates the HTTP request, such as a web browser.

Comment: @Martin Costello Thank you!